# Google Map API for android gives Unknown source error while adding ground overlay with BitmapDescriptor loaded from asset

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, gmsgroundoverlay

I use below code to add ground ovelay to google map using api 2 from android.

```
LatLng ne = currentHole.getNe();
    LatLng sw = currentHole.getSw();
    LatLngBounds mOverlayBound = new LatLngBounds(ne,sw);
    BitmapDescriptor mDesc= BitmapDescriptorFactory.
    fromAsset(currentHole.getGroundOverLay()); GroundOverlayOptions mOverlayOp = new GroundOverlayOptions().image(mDesc).positionFromBounds(mOverlayBound).zIndex(2); mOverlayOp.bearing(0);
    gOverLay = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(mOverlayOp);
```

All input parmeters are valid and it works fine when I load BitMapDescriptor from resource instead of asset and this code was working fine before recently I touched the code for some changes then it started showing error as below.

```
02-23 10:07:22.982: W/System.err(3538): java.lang.NullPointerException 

02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at com.google.k.a.cj.a(Unknown 

       Source) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at 
        com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.dc.<init>(Unknown Source) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.db.a(Unknown Source) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.eu.<init>(Unknown Source) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:182) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addGroundOverlay(Unknown Source) 
02-23 10:07:22.986: W/System.err(3538): at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(Unknown Source) --
```

Comment: Do you just need to add a image to your markers in your infoWindow?

Comment: The code above is to add ground overlay, it works fine when when I generate BitmapDescriptor from resources instead of asset.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the line

```
BitmapDescriptor mDesc= BitmapDescriptorFactory. fromAsset(currentHole.getGroundOverLay());
```

Which is probably giving you the NullpointerException. Make sure you just pass the String as the image stored in the assests directory of your project. May be the `currentHole.getGroundOverLay()` is not a valid image in the assests directory and hence it is giving a NullPointer.

Comment: The image path is perfect I checked and confirmed that, and you know it was a working code but suddenly without making any changes it started showing this error. I doubt if there is any change in Google Map API.

Comment: Yeah there are a lot of changes... But the thing is your logcat doesnt say anything about those. At which line you are getting the Null Pointer?

Comment: gOverLay = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(mOverlayOp); exactly on this line when I load BitmapDescriptorFactory. fromAsset, the image path and bound is perfect those are not null.